# Data Exchange Framework Pipeline Step is Missing at least one required plugin

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am getting the following error when running the pipeline bathc. "Pipeline step is missing at least one required plugin." I have an AddPlugins method in my pipeline step:

```
protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
{
  AddEndpointSettings(source, pipelineStep);
}
```

I also have it in my end point converter. I doesn't look like this gets hit:

```
 protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, Endpoint endpoint)
{
  var settings = new ContactSettings();
  settings.CollectionName = base.GetStringValue(source, "Collection Name");

  endpoint.Plugins.Add(settings);

}
```

I looked through the DEF dlls using dotPeek, but wasn't quite sure where this error is coming from. What could of I have missed? Thanks.

Processor code:

```
 public class ReadContactsStepProcessor : BaseReadDataStepProcessor
```

{
    public override bool CanProcess(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext)
    {
      return base.CanProcess(pipelineStep, pipelineContext);
    }
    public override void Process(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext)
    {
      base.Process(pipelineStep, pipelineContext);
    }
    protected override void ReadData(Endpoint endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext)
    {
      var contactSettings = pipelineStep.GetPlugin();
      if (contactSettings != null)
      {
        pipelineContext.PipelineBatchContext.Logger.Info(
            "Hello world! Create some items here..." + contactSettings.CollectionName);
      }

```
  //add the plugin to the pipeline context
  pipelineContext.Plugins.Add(contactSettings);
}
```

}

Comment: To fix it, we need to see what is pipeline step processor used. if your pipeline step processor is based on already excited, it means, it may require some plugins for correct work. Attribute usage is default implementation to assign required plugins. If base class has it, the method canprocess will check it  and throw an error if certain plugins are missed. .

Comment: I pasted the code. I based this on https://github.com/feniljacob/RSS-Feed-Provider-for-Data-Exchange-Framework/blob/master/Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.RSS%20Feed/Processors/PipelineSteps/ReadRssFeedStepProcessor.cs. The ReadData does not get called on my processor.

Comment: What is DEF version? I see when this error appears, it  should be displayed with missed plugin name.

Comment: I am using 1.3.

Comment: This is the missing plugin. " (pipeline step: Contacts Read Pipeline Step, missing plugins: Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.EndpointSettings)"

Comment: Does you converter for "ReadContactsStepProcessor" add EndpointSeetings to pipeline step plugins?

Comment: I think that is the part with the issue. I think my pipeline step is not setting the EndpointFrom. Working through that now. I will keep you posted.

Comment: So it looks this line is not working.  var endpointFrom = base.ConvertReferenceToModel<Endpoint>(source, ContactReadStepItemModel.EndpointFrom); I do see a value for EndPointFrom in source. So strange it is not picking it up.

Comment: Ok, now check if the field name of pipeline step processor is corresponding the ContactReadStepItemModel.EndpointFrom value. Field value should be ID of an item whose converter returns an Endpoint

Comment: I did check that. Field name is EndpointFrom on template and same name in the model value. If I do this I get a guid that does correspond to the endpoint. source.TryGetValue("EndpointFrom", out var endpointFrom);

Comment: So this is where it is failing. On the ConvertReferenceToModel I get a value for endpoing on this line: ItemModel referenceAsModel = this.GetReferenceAsModel(itemModel, fieldName); When the ConverttoModel is called though if fails on this line: IConverter<ItemModel, T> converter = itemModel.GetConverter<T>(this.ItemModelRepository);

Comment: It looks like the problem is what Vlad described: `referenceAsModel` cannot be converted to `<T>` (which, in this case, is `Endpoint`). Look at the item ID for `referenceAsModel`. Find that in Content Editor and make sure it is an endpoint item. 

If `referenceAsModel` **is** an endpoint item, then the problem is that the converter assigned to the endpoint item is not converting the item properly. You need to look at the converter type that is assigned to the endpoint item and see what is wrong.

Comment: I went back and changed that code. To the following and it looks like it adds the plug in.  var settings = new ContactSettings();

      var endpointFrom = this.ItemModelRepository.Get(new System.Guid(source["EndpointFrom"].ToString()));
      if (endpointFrom != null)
      {
        settings.CollectionName = endpointFrom["Collection Name"].ToString();
      }

      pipelineStep.Plugins.Add(settings);

Comment: Problem is I get the same message again. I also get this message which might be related. Not sure what order the messages appear. "Pipeline step will be skipped because the processor cannot processes the pipeline step"

Comment: Maybe you can serialize the items (and templates), along with the code and email it to me.

Comment: Sure let me find your contact info. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AdamConn I sent you message on Slack. I can't find your address on here. Can I contact you some other way if Slack does not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after talking to Adam and Vlad I figured out was wrong. First thing I needed was to define the endpoint settings in the pipeline step. I was doing the wrong plugin. When using BaseReadStepProcessor in your Pipeline processor endpoint settings must be added as a plugin.

```
protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
{
  AddEndpointSettings(source, pipelineStep);
}
private void AddEndpointSettings(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
{
  var settings = new EndpointSettings();
  settings.EndpointFrom = base.ConvertReferenceToModel<Endpoint>(source, ContactReadStepItemModel.EndpointFrom);
  pipelineStep.Plugins.Add(settings);
}
```

The second thing I had wrong was my spelling for Converter in my endpoint in Sitecore was off. I had an extra space.